# Bootstrap container-fluid vertical scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-scrolling

I already found many answers to this question, but not any seemed to work for me.
I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="sectionLeft">
        Sidebar Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And then I always get a Vertical-Scrollbar and i don't know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the `css`, can you include it too?

Comment: Please try to create fiddle or snippet to try it in action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. My main css-file was causing this problem since I had this:

```
 body{
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 9pt !important;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Where the `width: 100vw` caused the problem.